# How to unmanaged code from developer edition into production?

Tags: deployment, unmanaged-package

[image: Error on moving unmanaged code by clicking upload button]

Hi Folks,

I am trying to move a unmanaged package from developer edition into production which already contains one unmanaged package.

After adding the components I changed in developer edition and clicked upload. It is showing the error as show in the screenshot.

Please provide your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespaces are not used in unmanaged packages. In fact, even if your organization is namespaced, the namespace is removed from all components when it is uploaded as an unmanaged package so check line 501 of your code and remove that reference.

Comment: Namespace is reffered in many places not only on that line

Comment: try to remove at line 501. it should throw exception on next occurrence.